Pytest giving errors on parametrize
EDIT : It only works when I have named the variable as 'config' and no other names work.
import hashlib
import logging
from typing import Callable

import pytest
from pytest_embedded_idf.dut import IdfDut

EXPECT_TIMEOUT = 10

testdata = [2, 3, 4]


@pytest.mark.esp32s3
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", testdata)
def test_hello_world(dut: IdfDut, x):
    pass

This gives me the following errors
This is the error it gives
Kindly help with a solution of this problem. I run it on an esp32s3 device with UART usb connection.
My friend did not get any error while running the above code but i got the above error.
Error ->
============================================================================================================ ERRORS ============================================================================================================ 
____________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_hello_world[2] _____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:481: in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:674: in _listener
    return _listener_gn(**locals())
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\dut_factory.py:92: in _listener_gn
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(_pexpect_logfile), exist_ok=True)
E   NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 2}"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3_default... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_default... missing... try another place
INFO     root:conftest.py:130 found valid binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build
____________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_hello_world[3] _____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:481: in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:674: in _listener
    return _listener_gn(**locals())
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\dut_factory.py:92: in _listener_gn
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(_pexpect_logfile), exist_ok=True)
E   NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 3}"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3_default... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_default... missing... try another place
INFO     root:conftest.py:130 found valid binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build
____________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_hello_world[4] _____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:481: in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\plugin.py:674: in _listener
    return _listener_gn(**locals())
C:\Espressif\python_env\idf5.2_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\pytest_embedded\dut_factory.py:92: in _listener_gn
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(_pexpect_logfile), exist_ok=True)
E   NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 4}"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3_default... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_esp32s3... missing... try another place
WARNING  root:conftest.py:133 checking binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build_default... missing... try another place
INFO     root:conftest.py:130 found valid binary path: C:\Users\Inito\esp\v5.2.1\esp-idf\hello_world\build
========================================================================================================= Failed Cases ========================================================================================================= 
========================================================================== you can use --ignore-result-files or --ignore-result-cases to ignore them =========================================================================== 
esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 2}
esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 3}
esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 4}
=================================================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================================================== 
ERROR pytest_hello_world.py::test_hello_world[2] - NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 2}"
ERROR pytest_hello_world.py::test_hello_world[3] - NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 3}"
ERROR pytest_hello_world.py::test_hello_world[4] - NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: "C:\\Users\\Inito\\esp\\v5.2.1\\esp-idf\\pytest_embedded_log\\2024-05-25_15-46-55\\esp32s3.default.test_hello_world.{'x': 4}"
====================================================================================================== 3 errors in 0.36s ======================================================================================================= 


Does parametrize() work with indirect=True?

Please post the error as text, not a screenshot.

@KlausD. it also does not work work with '''indirect=True'''

"I run it on an esp32s3 device with UART usb connection." - Do you expect that this is necessary to know, in order to understand the problem? For example, did you try using the code on ordinary hardware (a desktop or laptop)? Can you reproduce the problem that way?

Based on the screenshot, it appears that the parametrize is functioning correctly. I see your test name (test_hello_world) followed by square brackets and the parametrize value in between. According to the error you post, it looks like you are using a fixture and problem occurs in setup stage. I suggest you to check code in your fixture before yielding.

@volkan it apparently works when I name the variable as 'config' instead of 'x'. Also I've only been using the inbuilt fixtures of pytest.
